# Slider within another slider

Tags: jquery

I have tried hard to get my jQuery slider to function within this panel switcher (which is basically also a slider) I'm using on my [one page website](http://openeye-design.no). However it will only work properly on `pageload`. I need it to call the content slider script again after visiting other panels on the page.

It's a known issue for the programmers behind the [jquery-content-panel-switcher](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-content-panel-switcher/wiki/Using_Other_Plugins_With_JCPS), and they recommend the `.live()` method but this doesn´t work for me either.

I'm guessing this can be solved by using an additional script, but I don't know which one.

Hope someone here can - or at least tell me what is causing this problem in this particular matter.

Comment: My UI impression of http://openeye-design.no/: A good design, but the animation is much to slow.

Comment: What does "my jQuery slider should function within this panel switcher" mean?

Answer (score 1):

One tip is don't listen for the`slide` event, listen for the`change` event, that is the only way you can allow changes in one slider to affect the second.

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Since .live will be deprecated, try using .on

http://api.jquery.com/on/

e.g.

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);
```

will be replaced by

```
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);  



$('#your_page_id').live("pagecreate", function(){
 //your code here
});
```

will be replaced by

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#your_page_id', function(){
     //your code here
});
```

Random example

```
$("#my_id").on("click", function(event){
    //execute slider code
});
```